# Spring AOP is not hijacking method with @Around annotation

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

Here is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.52.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
            <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0-alpha2</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
            <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is my aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Service
public class AspectLogger {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AspectLogger.class);

    @Around("execution(* com.xxx.model.bl.items.IPostProcessingService.postProcessingBulk(..))")
    public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        logger.info("before!");

        joinPoint.proceed(); //continue on the intercepted method

        logger.info("after!");
    }
}
```

PostProcessingService class:

```
@Component
public class PostProcessingService implements IPostProcessingService {
...
}
```

I was trying to point out the execution to the interface and as well the the class it self, but still i didnt see any logging, as well was trying to set it to the controller that using the IPostProcessingService interface but still the same results

I added as well to the application-conext:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

Did i miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that i miss 2 annotation in the `AspectLogger` class

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Component
public class AspectLogger {
}
```

Now it is working